# Postfix from address changed, mail being bounced

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, email, postfix, centos6

I have an Apache server which has been happily sending emails for the past few years - earlier this week the from address on all emails sent by postifx has changed and, as a result, 99% of messages are getting bounced or marked as spam.

I am not aware of any changes made to the server or DNS yet emails are being bounced and blacklisted.

In my maillog I have two messages sent 7 minutes apart - the first one is fine and gets sent but everything subsequent bounces:

```
Sep  3 08:04:52 web01 postfix/pickup[1760]: 9E75E490081: uid=48 from=<apache>
Sep  3 08:04:52 web01 postfix/cleanup[2597]: 9E75E490081: warning: header To: 
    RECIPIENT1, from local; from=<apache@domain.com>
Sep  3 08:04:52 web01 postfix/cleanup[2597]: 9E75E490081: warning: header 
    Subject: Subject from local; from=<apache@domain.com>
Sep  3 08:04:52 web01 postfix/cleanup[2597]: 9E75E490081: message-id
    <20140903080452.9E75E490081@web01.domain.com>
Sep  3 08:04:52 web01 postfix/qmgr[1069]: 9E75E490081: from=<apache@domain.com>, 
    size=850, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  3 08:05:06 web01 postfix/smtp[2600]: 9E75E490081: to=<RECIPIENT1>,
    relay=RELAY[XX.XX.XX.XX]:25, delay=14, delays=0.34/0.02/2.4/12, dsn=2.0.0, 
    status=sent (250 OK id=1XP5Yn-000AW9-Bm)
Sep  3 08:05:06 web01 postfix/qmgr[1069]: 9E75E490081: removed
```

The main difference is that the from address has changed from aopache@domain.com to apache.domain.domain and domain.com has changed to just domain:

```
Sep  3 08:11:31 web postfix/pickup[1065]: 35425490081: uid=48 from=<apache>
Sep  3 08:11:31 web postfix/cleanup[1634]: 35425490081: warning: header To: 
    RECIPIENT2, from local; from=<apache@domain.domain>
Sep  3 08:11:31 web postfix/cleanup[1634]: 35425490081: warning: header Subject: 
    Subject from local; from=<apache@domain.domain>
Sep  3 08:11:31 web postfix/cleanup[1634]: 35425490081: message-id
    <20140903081131.35425490081@web.domain>
Sep  3 08:11:31 web postfix/qmgr[1066]: 35425490081: from=<apache@domain.domain>, 
    size=855, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  3 08:11:35 web postfix/smtp[1637]: 35425490081: to=<RECIPIENT2>, 
    relay=RELAY2[XX.XX.XX.XX]:25, delay=4.8, delays=0.12/0.02/2.7/2, dsn=5.0.0, 
    status=bounced (host RELAY2[XX.XX.XX.XX] said: 550-Verification failed for 
    <apache@domain.domain> 550-The mail server could not deliver mail to 
    apache@domain.domain.  The account or domain may not exist, they may be 
    blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries. 550 Sender verify failed 
    (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Sep  3 08:11:36 web postfix/cleanup[1634]: 2497D554007: message-id=
    <20140903081136.2497D554007@web.domain>
Sep  3 08:11:36 web postfix/bounce[1639]: 35425490081: sender non-delivery 
    notification: 2497D554007
Sep  3 08:11:36 web postfix/qmgr[1066]: 2497D554007: from=<>, size=3591, 
    nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  3 08:11:36 web postfix/qmgr[1066]: 35425490081: removed
```

Any idea what could have caused this and, more importantly, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

## Using a bogus address as envelope sender is causing the issue.

The specific error messages you are receiving, indicate that this is the problem:

```
550-Verification failed for 
<apache@domain.domain> 550-The mail server could not deliver mail to 
apache@domain.domain.  The account or domain may not exist, they may be 
blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries. 550 Sender verify failed 
(in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

See where it says **"The account or domain may not exist"**

That's your problem. Use a valid address (and that includes using a valid domain) as your envelope sender, as well as in your From header.

Comment: Hi Joe - the problem is it used to show apache@domain.com and now it shows apache@domain.domain but I have no idea what changed. It worked prior and now it doesn't now - hostname shows web.domain so I assume I need to change that to web01@domain.com? Is that all I need to do?

Comment: Maybe. You may need to change whatever web application is doing the sending to use the correct sender info. Either way, thats really a different question. Why is the mail rejected? Because of the sender change. Why the sender change and how to fix, is a separate but related question.